# vector subscript out of range when logging in

Tags: c++, vector, range

I have searched for similar errors but could not find an answer that is relative to my code.
I have a log in system, where names and passwords are read in from a file into a vector.
I then count through the vector and match usernames and passwords, and I can log into my program using any of the name/password combinations held in the vector, however, if I were to type something that is not held in the vector or file for that matter it throws a run time error that the vector is out of range.
Please could anyone help with how I could catch the user input outside of the vector. I hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance and lets see how many down votes I can get this time. lol.

Sorry I didn't post any code, I posted question on my desktop and code is on my laptop. thanks.

```
 void loginScreen()
{
    vector <string> MyVec;
    string unTemp;
    string pwTemp;
    bool correct = true;


    cout << "Enter Your Username: ";
    cin >> unTemp; cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Your Password: ";
    cin >> pwTemp;

    fstream admin("admin.txt", ios::in || ios::out || ios::app);


    while (admin >> userName >> password)
    {
        MyVec.push_back(userName + " " + password);
    }

    admin.close();



    for (vector<string>::const_iterator i = MyVec.begin(); i != MyVec.end(); ++i)

    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= MyVec.size(); ++j)


        do{


        if (MyVec[j] == unTemp + " " + pwTemp)
            {
                cout << MyVec.size() << endl;
                cout << MyVec[j] << endl;
                correct;

                mainMenu();

            }



            else 
            {
                !correct;

            }


        } while (!correct);

    }

    }
```

Comment: You will need to show some code and the error message to get help. Please read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No code? Let me go fetch my crystal ball...

Comment: My debugger is out being fixed.  Could you use a debugger for me and single step through the code, *watching* the variables?   This way the subscript value would be known as well as the quantity of items in the vector.

Comment: Stop when you reach the end of the vector, not only when you find a valid combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is

```
        for (int j = 0; j <= MyVec.size(); ++j)
```

it should be

```
        for (int j = 0; j < MyVec.size(); ++j)
```

Using '<=' to end a loop is a huge red flag.  Nearly all loops start at 0 and are terminated by `< limit`.

Given you only ever use `j` to index into `MyVec` it would be even better to use a range-based for loop like:

```
        for (const auto &c : MyVec)
```

Also, where you say

```
         correct;
         ....
         !correct
```

This just means "evaluate the current value of `correct` and throw the result away".  I think you mean

```
         correct = true;
         ....
         correct = false;
```

... which actually changes the value!

Comment: Thank you Martin, but emitting my = from my for loop only allows me to read the [0] of the vector and does not progress forward if I use the username and password in the [1] or [2] vector. Also using the auto, then causes my 'if' statement to question [j]??

Comment: ok that's great, got it working a little better by removing the = in my for loop, I do not encounter the run time error now, however when I enter a password/username that does not exist the console just stays as it is. I will now work on this for a while before I ask for any more help. thanks again.

Comment: Oh right.  Sorry.  With the auto loop, you don't say `MyVec[j]`, you just say `c`instead.  Good luck!